# When I ping valid URL without www resolves to localhost instead of host server IP

Tags: macos, localhost, url

I'm having a problem where a valid URL kerfpress.com (without www.) is bringing up localhost when I ping on my Mac.

```
$ ping kerfpress.com
PING localhost (127.0.0.1): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 127.0.0.1: icmp_seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.052 ms
```

When I ping www.kerfpress.com it works fine:

```
$ ping www.kerfpress.com
PING www.kerfpress.com (195.234.10.136): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 195.234.10.136: icmp_seq=0 ttl=49 time=54.084 ms
```

This is only happening from my Mac OSX 10.7.5.  From other devices it seems to be accessing both fine.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: can you post your `/etc/hosts` on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com) for example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.kerfpress.com/ 
Is a valid website ... 
And probably you have created kerfpress.com on you localhost ... 
And that is reason why you getting that results !

Comment: Thanks mirkobrankovic - was an entry in hosts file that was causing it.

Comment: @Euan no problem, glad to help :D